# Node.js how to keep it running on CentOS?

Tags: node.js, centos

Recently I have setup Node, Express and Jade on a CentOS 6.5 box with no other web servers or anything. I have the site working but in order to keep it up and running I have to leave a putty window open with the server running. So far no issue but if I lose power or internet my SSH connection is lost and the site goes down. Is there a way to keep my app.js running regardless of my SSH state?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to [daemonize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daemon_%28computing%29) your application. There are many different ways to do it.

1. You can use [daemon](https://github.com/indexzero/daemon.node) module for node.js.
2. You can start your application inside of 'screen'.
3. You can start your application with nohup util:

   ```
   sudo -u [appuser] nohup node [path_to_your_app] > [path_to_log_file] 2>&1 &
   ```

Comment: Thanks I actually ended up using forever which uses daemon.node. Appreciate the help! http://blog.nodejitsu.com/keep-a-nodejs-server-up-with-forever

Answer (score 0):

i know this is old; but, my CentOS will not "sudo yum install forever" - gives error: "No package forever available". so i tried

```
"sudo -u [appuser] nohup node [path_to_your_app] > [path_to_log_file] 2>&1 &", where;

[appuser] = admin
[path_to_your_app] = server.js
[path_to_log_file] = log.txt.
```

still, in 5 min the sever timed out due to "broken pipe" and web page running via node server, stopped.